# How do I embed a Flash 360 tour into My Maps in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How do I embed a FLASH 360 TOUR into MY MAPS in GOOGLE MAPS? 
Everytime I paste a code other than a youtube video embed code it deletes itself. These fellows did it somehow: http://virtualafrica.co.za/googlemaps/
I don't know how so I need some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The map used on that site is not a My Maps map, but a customized map built using JavaScript and the Maps API. If Google doesn't let you paste Flash embeds into My Maps, you'll likely have to code it yourself using the API.

Comment: Thanks. Which API do I need to sign up for? MAPS API, MAPS  API PREMIER, GOOGLE EARTH PRO, EARTH ENTERPRISE?

Comment: You can get started with the free account and later decide to upgrade if you feel the need, but I'd guess the free one is quite enough for you. The differences in the API accounts are mostly related to whether you're allowed to use the map in a non-public app or not, and the amount of traffic you may generate. You should read the terms of service to decide which one is right for you.